# Why are there no grazing impacts on the Moon?

Tags: astrophysics, collision, moon, asteroids

Round craters seem to indicate a 90 degree impact from a meteor...  But meteors should come from all directions, shouldn't there be some elliptical craters and some trenches dug ending in essentially half craters.

Comment: The Imbrium impactor hit the moon at about 30 degree angle: https://news.brown.edu/articles/2016/07/imbrium

Comment: Thanks for that info!, but I could rephrase the question to why are there so many apparent 90 degree impacts on the Moon...  But your comment is helpful.

Comment: Your basic problem starts right at the beginning: *"Round craters seem to indicate a 90 degree impact from a meteor"*. You can test this with a metal baking dish full of flour or something similar. But do it outside 'cause it's kind of messy. Short-short version: round craters result from all the angles that you can generate that way.

Comment: Ok that's testable... but you seem to be saying coming in at a grazing angle would leave a round crater.. no trench leading up to the crater...   see this earth impact https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_impact_craters_on_Earth#/media/File:Vredefort_Dome_STS51I-33-56AA.jpg   Where it looks like the meteor or whatever hit at an angle.

Comment: Neil deGrasse Tyson addresses this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PhHtBqsGAoA&feature=youtu.be&t=6592) (1:49:52 in case it doesn't open to the right time for some reason). A quick summary is that if a projectile has more kinetic energy than the energy binding it together, the impact will cause the projectile itself to explode spherically.

Comment: ok, why not make that an answer?   But also, is he saying that all meteors had higher kinetic energy than binding energy?  There were no impacts in 4 billion years with slower impactors...

Comment: I was never able to test very high speed grazing impacts personally and suspect that you can reach a set of conditions where you get extended craters, but quite shallow impacts still make circular craters. To ther point that there is much, *much* more solid angle for round craters than other shapes.

Comment: Related: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-are-impact-craters-al/ . This SciAm article answer this very question extremely well.

Answer (score 3):

A projectile hitting a water surface under any angle causes a circular wave. The reason is that the surface is a uniform medium so the propagation speed does not depends on direction. The same is the case for a solid surface.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually a lot of grazing impacts on the Moon. Messier is a good example. 45 degrees is the most common impact angle, with decreasing likelihood as 90 degrees (vertical) and 0 degrees (horizontal) are approached. The probability of impact angle follows a sin curve.

Part of the issue is the energies involved. In planetary scale impacts, the energy imparted to the surface is so high and creates such a large excavation event that no trace of the obliquity (fancy term for "low angle") remains in the crater itself. It just looks round. It isn't until the impact angle gets low, really low, like 5 degrees or less, that planetary impacts leave an elongated crater (like Messier).

The easier way to tell if a crater impacted obliquely is the ejecta pattern. Oblique craters create this characteristic pattern called a butterfly pattern in which there is a forbidden zone in the uprange direction (back in the direction from which the impactor came) and a zone of reduced ejecta (sometimes forming a forbidden zone) in the downrange direction. Changes in ejecta pattern occur as high as 45 degrees with an uprange forbidden zone. The full butterfly pattern doesn't really start until about 15 degrees or less.

And, to make matters horribly complex, those angles all change based on target properties (how strong is the material, is it solid rock or sand? Or maybe it's ice! Is there layering in the material; if so, what are the properties of the different layers? Does it have water in it that will vaporize and add energy to the impact event? Is there an atmosphere? What's the surface gravity?) and impactor properties (is it solid, an aggregate of tiny particles clumped together? Is it rock or ice? Is it traveling at a few kilometers per second or 50 km/s?).

Comment: Welcome to Physics! You might also note that the cloud of ejecta has the same total momentum as the initial momentum of the ejected material. Consider the Chixulub event, where an object with diameter 10km excavated a crater with depth 20km and diameter 180km; clearly the vast majority of the ejected material came from the Earth, not from the impactor.

Comment: Do you have a link to a derivation of your sine-ish (or perhaps $\sin^2$-ish) angle distribution? I have a follow-up question about that distribution in terms of "solid" angle.

Comment: This link is good for some general reading: http://geosci.uchicago.edu/~kite/doc/Melosh_ch_6.pdf.


For info specific to oblique impactors: https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.earth.28.1.141


I'm not sure you'll have access to the latter. I'm having trouble finding an open source. 


The way I think of it is that the Earth is a ball spinning so fast (compared to the rate of incoming impactors) that any intersection on the surface just becomes a random selection of a point on one hemisphere. So it comes down to cross sectional area and local surface angle.

Answer (score 1):

National Geographic had an article in the early to mid 1960's about this topic (1964 I think).  They shot grains of sand from an accelerator into a bed of sand.  Anything but an extremely oblique angle would simply make a round crater.  Unless it is updated with more accurate tests to the direct contrary, there is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also suspect there’s a gravitational aspect to this.  The craters we see were big enough to make a sizable pock mark, but small enough to not catastrophically destroy the moon.  That means the moon would have a significant gravitational influence on a small incoming meteor, creating a tendency toward more vertical impacts.  A completely unsupported hypothesis on my part that may not hold up well to extremely high projectile velocities.